# What is the best way to interpolate Isotopic data and display them?

Tags: climate-models, mapping, python, isotopic, interpolation

I want to interpolate isotope data of precipitation and display it on a map. The data are available as a CSV file.

```
   Country Latitude Longitude  Altitude  Sample Name        Date      H2  Year  month      dates
5         DE  511.622   149.506       238       199706  15.06.1997   -71.7  1997      6 1997-06-15
6         DE  511.622   149.506       238       199707  15.07.1997   -70.1  1997      7 1997-07-15
7         DE  511.622   149.506       238       199708  15.08.1997   -64.5  1997      8 1997-08-15
8         DE  511.622   149.506       238       199709  15.09.1997   -39.1  1997      9 1997-09-15
9         DE  511.622   149.506       238       199710  15.10.1997   -56.4  1997     10 1997-10-15
...      ...      ...       ...       ...          ...         ...     ...   ...    ...        ...
4995      DE  490.422   121.019       365       201304  15.04.2013  -41.86  2013      4 2013-04-15
4996      DE  490.422   121.019       365       201305  15.05.2013  -68.03  2013      5 2013-05-15
4997      DE  490.422   121.019       365       201306  15.06.2013  -54.98  2013      6 2013-06-15
4998      DE  490.422   121.019       365       201307  15.07.2013  -39.23  2013      7 2013-07-15
4999      DE  490.422   121.019       365       201308  15.08.2013  -46.93  2013      8 2013-08-15
```

With the package Pykrige I could make first interpolations, but I want my data to be interpolated and displayed similar to the R package:

https://bookdown.org/content/782/introduction.html.

Is there a similar package for Python, which is often used in geostatisics to represent chemicals in precipitation? I ask this because I have not found anything myself.

Comment: Hi Weiss, I believe a similar question you posted earlier was closed for being opinion-based.  Could you please [edit] the question and remove the opinionated pieces ("good solution" and "do you think")?  The question if a suitable package exists is probably a good question.

Comment: Thanks for your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think there is no similar package. Therefore, the best approach is to do the interpolation with the package Pykrige and for displaying the data I would recommend the package Basemap (unfortunately, I have not used catropy, but I can say that Basemap is well usable even by non-Python affine users).
Good Luck

Comment: Basemap is now deprecated in favour of cartopy.
just trying to install it will shorten your life

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment; I hope It will NOT shorten my life :-)

Comment: (Pretty sure yair was half attempting at humor.  It certainly can be frustrating sometimes though!)